# How to check if a PDF file is signed or not using iTextsharp in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, itext, sign

I have a PDF file and I want to check whether it is signed by digital signature or not. using iTextsharp, the code in C#.

Comment: What code are you using and what specific issue are you having with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would advise taking a look at the official examples.

They contain e.g. an example "SignatureInfo" which outputs multiple information items on all signatures embedded in a PDF; thus, they in particular determine whether a file is signed at all.

---

It you are using iTextSharp 5.5.x, your pivotal code is this

```
public void InspectSignatures(String path) {
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
    AcroFields fields = reader.AcroFields;
    List<String> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();
    SignaturePermissions perms = null;
    foreach (String name in names) {
        Console.WriteLine("===== " + name + " =====");
        perms = InspectSignature(fields, name, perms);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

*(from the iTextSharp example [C5_02_SignatureInfo.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/tutorial/blob/master/signatures/chapter5/C5_02_SignatureInfo/C5_02_SignatureInfo.cs))*

As you see, the method `AcroFields.GetSignatureNames()` gets you the names of all signed signature fields. If that list is non-empty, the PDF is signed.

---

If you are using iText 7 for .Net, your pivotal code is this:

```
public virtual void InspectSignatures(String path)
{
    // System.out.println(path);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path));
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, false);
    SignaturePermissions perms = null;
    SignatureUtil signUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDoc);
    IList<String> names = signUtil.GetSignatureNames();
    foreach (String name in names)
    {
        System.Console.Out.WriteLine("===== " + name + " =====");
        perms = InspectSignature(pdfDoc, signUtil, form, name, perms);
    }
    System.Console.Out.WriteLine();
}
```

*(from the iText 7 for .Net example [C5_02_SignatureInfo.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.publications/itext.publications.signatures/itext/samples/signatures/chapter05/C5_02_SignatureInfo.cs))*

As you see, the method `SignatureUtil.GetSignatureNames()` gets you the names of all signed signature fields. If that list is non-empty, the PDF is signed.

---

By the way, as you did not specify any further, I assume you mean regular integrated PDF signatures, in particular neither detached signatures nor XFA signatures.

Comment: This should be marked as the solution! This works great for me.

Comment: You (as the person who asked) are the one who can do that: Click the tick at the upper left of the answer.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm trying to get XFA signatures.  Is this even possible?

Comment: What kind of xfa do you use?